# R is symmetric and transitive relation, if and only if $R = R^{-1}\circ R$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations, function-and-relation-composition

How do I prove that the following:

> Let $R$ be a (binary) relation on a set. Prove that $R$ is symmetric and transitive relation, if and only if $R = R^{-1}\circ R$.

Here, $R^{-1} \circ R$ is defined as the relation $\{(u,v) | \exists x, uR^{-1}x \land xRv\}$, where $xRu$ means $\left(x,u\right) \in R$.

I only have a problem with assuming the 2nd, and deriving the first, any tips on the proof technique?

Comment: If a relation $\mathcal{R}$ is both symmetric and transitive, isn't it also *reflexive*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $R = R^{-1} \circ R$.

Let $(a,b) \in R$. Since $(a,b) \in R^{-1} \circ R$, there is $c$ such that $(a,c) \in R^{-1}$ and $(c,b) \in R$.

So $(c,a) \in R$. Then, $(a,c) \in R^{-1}$, so $(a,a) \in R^{-1} \circ R = R$, so $(b,a) \in R^{-1} \circ R = R$.

So $R$ is symmetric.

Let $(a,b),(b,c) \in R$. By the above, $(b,a) \in R$, so $(a,b) \in R^{-1}$, so $(a,c) \in R^{-1} \circ R = R$

So $R$ is transitive.

---

Let $R$ be symmetric and transitive.

Then, let $(a,b) \in R$. Since $R$ is symmetric, $(b,a) \in R$, so $(a,b) \in R^{-1}$. Since $R$ is transitive, $(b,b) \in R$. Therefore, $(a,b) \in R^{-1} \circ R$.

Let $(a,b) \in R^{-1} \circ R$, and let $(a,c) \in R^{-1}$ and $(c,b) \in R$. So $(c,a) \in R$. Since $R$ is symmetric, $(a,c) \in R$. Since $R$ is transitive, $(a,b) \in R$.

Therefore, for all $(a,b)$, $(a,b) \in R \iff (a,b) \in R^{-1} \circ R$, so $R = R^{-1} \circ R$ by axiom of extensionality.

Answer (score 1):

**Preparations**:

$\newcommand{\op}[2]{ \left\langle #1 ,\, #2 \right\rangle }$
$\newcommand{\rel}[1]{ \mathcal{#1} }$
$\newcommand{\dom}[1]{ \mathrm{dom} \ {#1} }$
$\newcommand{\ran}[1]{ \mathrm{ran} \ {#1} }$

Define *ordered pair*:

$$\op{x}{y} = \left\{\left\{x\right\},\,\left\{x,\,y\right\}\right\}$$

Define *domain* and *range* of *relation*:

\begin{align}
\dom{R} &= \left\{ x \in \cup\cup\rel{R} \mid \exists y :\: \op{x}{y} \in \rel{R} \right\}, \\
\ran{R} &= \left\{ x \in \cup\cup\rel{R} \mid \exists t :\: \op{x}{y} \in \rel{R} \right\}.
\end{align}

[image]

---

If $X$ and $Y$ are sets, and $R$ is a relation between $X$ and $Y$,
i.e. $\rel{R} \subseteq X \times Y$.

Let $\rel{T}$ is a composite relation on $Y$,
i.e. $\rel{T} \subseteq Y \times Y$,
which satisfies $\rel{T} = \rel{R}^{-1}\circ\rel{R}$.

Assume $\op{x}{y} \in \rel{R},\; x \in \dom{R} \subseteq X,\; y \in \ran{R} \subseteq Y$.

\begin{align}
\op{x}{y} \in \rel{R}
&\implies \op{y}{x} \in \rel{R}^{-1} \\
&\implies \op{y}{y} \in \rel{R}^{-1}\circ\rel{R} \\
&\implies \op{x}{x} \in \rel{T}
\end{align}

Therefore, the composite relation $\rel{T}$ is *reflexive*.

Assume $\op{a}{b} \in \rel{T},\; a \in \dom{T} \subseteq Y,\; b \in \ran{T} \subseteq Y$.

\begin{align}
\op{a}{b} \in \rel{T}
&\implies \op{a}{b} \in \rel{R}^{-1}\circ\rel{R} \\
&\implies \exists t \in X :\: \op{a}{t} \in \rel{R}^{-1} \;\land\; \op{t}{b} \in \rel{R} \\
&\implies \exists t \in X :\: \op{b}{t} \in \rel{R}^{-1} \;\land\; \op{t}{a} \in \rel{R} \\
&\implies \op{b}{a} \in \rel{R}^{-1}\circ\rel{R} \\
&\implies \op{b}{a} \in \rel{T}
\end{align}

Therefore, the composite relation $\rel{T}$ is *symmetric*.

**Sufficiency**:

Given $\rel{R} = \rel{R}^{-1}\circ\rel{R}$, because $\rel{R}^{-1}\circ\rel{R}$ is both *reflexive* and *symmetric*, $\rel{R}$ has the same properties.

Suppose $\ran{R} \cap \dom{R} \neq \varnothing$, hence $\exists b :\: \op{a}{b} \in \rel{R}$, $\op{b}{c} \in \rel{R}$,
\begin{align}
\op{a}{b} \in \rel{R} \land \op{b}{c} \in \rel{R}
&\implies
\op{a}{b} \in \rel{R}^{-1} \land \op{b}{c} \in \rel{R} \\
&\implies
\op{a}{c} \in \rel{R}^{-1}\circ\rel{R} \\
&\implies
\op{a}{c} \in \rel{R}
\end{align}

Therefore, $\rel{R}$ is *transitive* as well.

**Necessity**:

If $\rel{R}$ is both *symmetric* and *transitive*, assume $\op{x}{y} \in \rel{R},\;\op{y}{z} \in \rel{R},\;\op{x}{z} \in \rel{R}$,
\begin{align}
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
\op{x}{z} \in \rel{R} \\
\op{y}{z} \in \rel{R}
\end{array} \right.
&\implies
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
\op{z}{x} \in \rel{R} \\
\op{z}{y} \in \rel{R}
\end{array} \right. \\
&\implies
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
\op{x}{z} \in \rel{R}^{-1} \\
\op{z}{y} \in \rel{R}
\end{array} \right. \\
&\implies
\op{x}{y} \in \rel{R}^{-1}\circ\rel{R} \\
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
\op{x}{y} \in \rel{R}^{-1}\circ\rel{R} \\
\op{x}{y} \in \rel{R}
\end{array} \right.
&\implies
\rel{R} = \rel{R}^{-1}\circ\rel{R}
\end{align}

---

All in all, $\rel{R}$ is symmetric and transitive if and only if $\rel{R} = \rel{R}^{-1}\circ\rel{R}$.